# Select rows without nested associated records

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having a very simple table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.employees (id int PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE dbo.assignments (id int PRIMARY KEY, employee_id int );
CREATE TABLE dbo.contracts (id int PRIMARY KEY, assignment_id int );
CREATE TABLE dbo.tasks (id int PRIMARY KEY, contract_id int );
```

Employee -< Assignments -< Contracts -< Tasks

I want to select all employees that do not have any associated tasks.

What would be the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: You can `inner join` first 3 tables and use `not in` for the 4th.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id 
from employees E 
where not exists (
                select * 
                from assignments A 
                     join contracts C on A.ID = C.assignment_id
                     join tasks T on C.ID = T.contract_id
                where A.employee_id = E.id)
```

Comment: In the end I went with @Mladen Prajdic solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can `inner join` first 3 tables and use `not in` for the 4th.

```
select 
 e.* 
from dbo.employees e
 inner join dbo.assignments a on a.employee_id = e.id
 inner join dbo.contracts c on c.assignment_id = a.id
where c.id not in (select distinct contract_id from dbo.tasks)
```

Comment: I guess I'd need `DISTINCT` in case employee has multiple assignments.

Answer (score 0):

Add EMPLOYEE_ID to the TASK table. Then you can check if COUNT(EMPLOYEE_ID) is zero.

Note that the way you have defined these entities forces you to "walk" the whole path from employee to contract to assignment to task. Adding the natural keys to each entity will enable you to go directly to the data you need. You can still keep the identity columns for index efficiency.

Natural key recommendations:
CONTRACT (EMPLOYEE_ID,CONTRACT_ID);
ASSIGNMENT (EMPLOYEE_ID, CONTRACT_ID, ASSIGNMENT_ID);
TASK (EMPLOYEE_ID, CONTRACT_ID, ASSIGNMENT_ID, TASK_ID).

Note that these should all be optional (1:M) relationships.